# JayData handling connection errors

Tags: jaydata

I was wandering how I could handle specific connectivity errors when instanciating an Odata store.

```
var store =    new Entities.EntityModel({
            name: 'oData',
            oDataServiceHost: App.endPoint + 'events/',
            maxDataServiceVersion: "2.0",
            extraHeaders: {apikey: App.credentials.apikey}
        });
```

after this I would like to know if my store is connected to its endpoint. I would I do this without issuing a dummy query?

Is the 'onReady' function fired when a connection has been made or only when the store is initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the static way as in your example then onReady means that all internal structure is initialized so you can start using JayData but it does not mean that your oData endpoint is working. You'll get error when you try to really access your endpoint.
If you use the initService method which downloads $metadata and builds the model in memory on the fly then JayData must be able to talk to your odata endpoint.